# How to pass list for "in" condition in couchbase n1ql in java?

Tags: java, couchbase

```
List<String> spotIdList = new ArrayList<>();
list.add("spot-1");
String historyQry = "SELECT refId ,deviceId as senseId, lastLogAt as lastSeenTime,spotId, META(`beacon-core`).cas as _CAS, "
                    + "META(`beacon-core`).id as _ID  from `beacon-core` WHERE _class='LiveState'  "
                    + "and deploymentId=$deploymentId and (spotId in $spotIds) and live='true' ORDER BY refId ";
            JsonObject params = JsonObject.create().put("deploymentId", deploymentId).put("spotId", spotIdList);
            List<SpotTagView> tags = coreTemplate.findByN1QL(N1qlQuery.parameterized(historyQry, params), SpotTagView.class);
```

Above code is how I tried.
I think I can do this by creating a string by iterating this list. Is there any better way.

Answer (score 0):

The same code works fine. Issue was a spelling mistake. In JsonObject instead of put spotId, it is spotIds.